# How can an element of a fixed size (canvas) be resized in a flex container?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

An HTML canvas element can be automatically resized by the dynamics of a HTML page: Maybe because its style properties are set to a percentage value, or maybe because it is inside a flex container.
Thereby the content of the canvas gets resized as well: Because of the interpolation the canvas content looks blurred (loss of resolution).

In order to keep the resolution to the maximum, one must render the canvas content based on the current pixel size of the element.

This fiddle shows how this can be done with the help of the function getComputedStyle: https://jsfiddle.net/fx98gmu2/1/

```
setInterval(function() {
  var computed = getComputedStyle(canvas);
  var w = parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue("width"), 10);
  var h = parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue("height"), 10);

  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  // re-rendering of canvas content...
}, 2000); // intentionally long to see the effect
```

With a setTimeout function I'm updating the width and height of the canvas to the computed values of these properties.

As the fiddle shows, this works only when increasing the size of the window. Whenever the window size gets decreased, the canvas (item of the flexbox) stays fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set its `flex-basis` to 0, allow it to shrink with `flex-shrink`, and don't force any minimum width:

```css
#canvas {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
setInterval(function() {
  var computed = getComputedStyle(canvas),
      w = parseInt(computed.width, 10),
      h = parseInt(computed.height, 10);
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, h/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.stroke();
}, 2000); // intentionally long to see the effect
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;  
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div>something else...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AntonHarald You probably use an old Chrome version which doesn't support the new `min-width: auto` default yet. Without `min-width: 0`, when you reduce the window, the canvas doesn't shrink.

Comment: Note that this solution still shows distorted canvas - you see circle as ellipse. For short amount of time but still.

Comment: @c-smile [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) can be used to prevent the distortion.

Comment: object-fit is even not in the set of approved specifications. And yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: @c-smile `object-fit` is defined in a Candidate Recommendation spec, so it's more stable than Flexbox, which is only a Working Draft. Anyways, there is no magical way to resize a canvas and obtain a perfect image, you must redraw it, which is what OP is doing. The problem was that the canvas was not flexing correctly, the distortion is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the canvas into a container with `overflow:hidden` and set canvas dimensions to dimensions of that container:

```js
window.setTimeout( function() {
  var div = $("div");
  div.find("canvas").attr( { width:div.width(), height:div.height()} );
})
```

```css
canvas { background:gold; display:block; }

div { width:50%; height:50%; border:1px solid; overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas width="200" height="100" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot as in my case the canvas was being resized by a library to be larger than the flexbox container element and causing the container to be oversized before I could re-set the canvas size.  Adding overflow fixed that.  Thanks!